# Parsing XML Document using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have a quite complex XML document, at least for me, with several informations on it, I tried checking the lxml library for the task, but I'm facing difficulties.
How can I do when I have 2 measValue measObjLdn, and I want the values back

```
KPI                    GRUPO      VALOR
avgMemoryUtilization1M  CP-ISA      72 
avgMemoryUtilization1M  CP-ISA2     86
avgPDPUtilization       1           29
avgPDPUtilization       2           32
```

The XML Document I have is quite something like the one below:

```
            <measInfo measInfoId="KPISystemCP-ISA">
        <granPeriod duration="PT300S" endTime="2019-05-14T12:05:01-03:00" />
        <measType p="1">VS.avgCpuUtilization</measType>
        <measType p="2">VS.avgMemoryUtilization</measType>
        <measType p="3">VS.avgMemoryUtilization1M</measType>
        <measType p="4">VS.SDFsFpUtilization</measType>
        <measType p="5">VS.SDFsLcpUtilization</measType>
        <measType p="6">VS.avgVmFpCpuNicUsage</measType>
        <measType p="7">VS.avgVmFpCpuWorkerUsage</measType>
        <measType p="8">VS.avgVmFpCpuSchedulerUsage</measType>
        <measType p="9">VS.avgVmFpCpuCollapsedUsage</measType>
        <measType p="10">VS.avgVmFpCpuCombinedUsage</measType>
        <measType p="11">VS.hwCfgBitsInfo</measType>
        <measValue measObjLdn="KPI=System,GroupName=CP-ISA,group=1,slot=3,mda=1">
            <r p="1">1</r>
            <r p="2">72</r>
            <r p="3">72</r>
            <r p="4">0.00</r>
            <r p="5">0.00</r>
            <r p="6">0.00</r>
            <r p="7">0.05</r>
            <r p="8">0.00</r>
            <r p="9">0.00</r>
            <r p="10">0.00</r>
            <r p="11">4</r>
        </measValue>
        <measValue measObjLdn="KPI=System,GroupName=CP-ISA2,group=2,slot=4,mda=1">
            <r p="1">1</r>
            <r p="2">86</r>
            <r p="3">86</r>
            <r p="4">0.00</r>
            <r p="5">0.00</r>
            <r p="6">0.00</r>
            <r p="7">0.05</r>
            <r p="8">0.00</r>
            <r p="9">0.00</r>
            <r p="10">0.00</r>
            <r p="11">7</r>
        </measValue>
    </measInfo>
    <measInfo>
        <granPeriod duration="PT300S" endTime="2019-05-14T12:05:01-03:00" />
        <measType p="1">VS.avgUtilization</measType>
        <measType p="2">VS.avgPDPUtilization</measType>
        <measType p="3">VS.avgPDPUtilization1M</measType>
        <measValue measObjLdn="KPI=System2,GroupName=1,group=1,slot=3,mda=1">
            <r p="1">1</r>
            <r p="2">29</r>
            <r p="3">99</r>
        </measValue>
        <measValue measObjLdn="KPI=System2,GroupName=2,group=2,slot=4,mda=1">
            <r p="1">1</r>
            <r p="2">32</r>
            <r p="3">16</r>
        </measValue>
    </measInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `find_all()` method in BeautifulSoup.

To break apart your problem, first you need to get each `measInfo` element

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')
measinfos = soup.find_all('measinfo')
```

This returns a `ResultSet` object containing your 2 `measInfo` elements that we can loop over.

Looking at the first element for example sake, we can parse this out to get some useful information.

```
measinfo = measinfos[0]  # First item in ResultSet
measinfoid = measinfo.get('measinfoid')  # get the measInfoId (such as KPISystemCP-ISA)
meastypes = measinfo.find_all('meastype')  # get all the measType tags to be able to map the correct values
measvalues = measinfo.find_all('measvalue')  # get all the `measValue` elements
```

We can put these "labels" into a dict to make it easier to map to the values later

```py
meastypes_dict = {}
    for meastype in meastypes:
        meastypes_dict[meastype.attrs['p']] = meastype.text
```

`meastype.attrs['p']` finds the `p` attribute and returns the value

Now the labels are ready. Moving onto the values, let's look at the first `measValue` element for example sake. We will loop through this and assign a label to each of the values.

```py
measvalue = measvalues[0]  # First item in ResultSet
measobjldn = measvalue.get('measobjldn')  # get the measObjLdn (such as KPI=System,GroupName=CP-ISA,...)
for result in measvalue.find_all('r'):  # loop through values
    label = meastypes_dict[result.attrs['p']]  # Using the `p` attribute from the value element, we can find which label this corresponds to
    value = result.text  # The value of the element
    print(measinfoid, measobjldn, label, value)
```

Final code:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')
measinfos = soup.find_all('measinfo')
for measinfo in measinfos:
    measinfoid = measinfo.get('measinfoid')
    meastypes = measinfo.find_all('meastype')
    measvalues = measinfo.find_all('measvalue')
    meastypes_dict = {}
    for meastype in meastypes:
        meastypes_dict[meastype.attrs['p']] = meastype.text

    for measvalue in measvalues:
        measobjldn = measvalue.get('measobjldn')
        for result in measvalue.find_all('r'):
            label = meastypes_dict[result.attrs['p']]
            value = result.text 
            print(measinfoid, measobjldn, label, value)
```

Comment: Excelente! muchas gracias!  and how can I put <granPeriod duration>  and "endTime" on all lines and then put it in inflixdb?